# Karma jasmine and angular controller using 'Controller as' syntax (this instead of $scope)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to set up karma to make some unit tests but I can't manage to make it work on a basic example :

This is the controller file :

```
angular.module('balrogApp.requests', [
  /* Dependancies */
])
  // Routes configuration
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    /* $routeProvider configuration */
  }])
  .controller('requestsController', function(Requests, Users, Projects, RequestsComments, CostEstimations,
                                             Regions, growl, $route, $rootScope, $scope, $location) {
    this.test = 'test42';

/* ... */

});
```

This is the test file :

```
describe('requestsController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('balrogApp.requests'));

  var ctrl;
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    ctrl = $controller('requestsController');
  }));

  it('should have test = "test42"', function(){
    expect(ctrl.test).toBe("test42");
  });
});
```

But this error is thrown :

> Chrome 43.0.2357 (Windows 7 0.0.0) requestsController should have test
>   = "test42" FAILED
>           Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- requestsController
>           http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20requestsController
>               at C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
>               at C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4289:19
>               at Object.getService [as get] (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
>               at C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4294:45
>               at getService (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
>               at invoke (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4469:13)
>               at Object.instantiate (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4486:27)
>               at C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9151:28
>               at C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1882:12
>               at Object. (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/tests/requests.js:6:12)
>           Error: Declaration Location
>               at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2409:25)
>               at Suite. (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/tests/requests.js:5:14)
>               at C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/tests/requests.js:1:1
>           TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
>               at Object. (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/tests/requests.js:10:16)
>   Chrome 43.0.2357 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR
>   (0.108 secs / 0.087 secs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$scope` (on which your controller depends on) is a so-called "local", i.e. it is specific to the instance of the controller and does not live in the dependency injection container. You have to provide it yourself, e.g. as:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    ctrl = $controller('requestsController', { $scope: $rootScope.$new() });
}));
```

Since you are creating a new scope, it would be good to destroy it after the test:

```
var scope;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('requestsController', { $scope: scope });
}));

afterEach(function() {
    scope.$destroy();
});
```