# What happens when you do not use $destroy() after creating an instance using $new() when unit testing AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angularjs-controller

I was looking for ways to unit test AngularJs when using the "controller as vm" style. I came across this ([Karma jasmine and angular controller using 'Controller as' syntax (this instead of $scope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762229/karma-jasmine-and-angular-controller-using-controller-as-syntax-this-instead)) question.

The person who provided the answer pointed out that since the "controller as vm" pattern uses this instead of $scope that an instance of $scope must be created.

The person who answered also pointed out that since you are creating an instance that it must be destroyed.

What happens when it is not destroyed?

Comment: nothing much happens, other than excess memory allocated for an object.  too many instances that aren't destroyed could slow down your tests, though....

Comment: When you destroy a scope in angular it triggers an event on the instance that allows the developer of the component to do any cleanup (remove event listeners, free memory, etc.).  Like Claies said not going to generally matter in the case of unit tests so far as I know.